# Spring Boot + Apache CXF: why can't find wsdl?

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, spring-boot, cxf

Collegues, I am still trying "to make friends all" Spring-Boot, Tomcat and web service implementation class:

```
@javax.jws.WebService(
                      serviceName = "ServiceForApp",
                      portName = "ServiceEndPoind",
                      targetNamespace = "http://new.webservice.namespace",
                      endpointInterface = "com.comp.appserv.WebServiceInterface",
                          wsdlLocation = "resources/WebService.wsdl"
                          )

public class ServiceEndPoindImpl implements WebServiceInterface {logic};
```

I have an application class:

```
package com.comp.config;


import org.apache.cxf.Bus;
import org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.SpringBus;
import org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl;
import org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import com.comp.appserv.ServiceEndPoindImpl;

import javax.xml.ws.Endpoint;


@SpringBootApplication
public class Application  {

    public static final String SERVLET_MAPPING_URL_PATH = "/soap/*";
    public static final String SERVICE_NAME_URL_PATH = "/app";

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean dispatcherServlet() {
        return new ServletRegistrationBean(new CXFServlet(), SERVLET_MAPPING_URL_PATH);
    }


    @Bean(name = Bus.DEFAULT_BUS_ID)
    // <bean id="cxf" class="org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.SpringBus">
    public SpringBus springBus() {
        return new SpringBus();
    }

    @Bean
    // <jaxws:endpoint id="app" implementor="com.dlizarra.app.ws.AppImpl" address="/app">
    public Endpoint app() {
        Bus bus = (Bus) applicationContext.getBean(Bus.DEFAULT_BUS_ID);
        Object implementor = new ServiceEndPoindImpl();
        EndpointImpl endpoint = new EndpointImpl(bus, implementor);
        endpoint.publish(SERVICE_NAME_URL_PATH);
        return endpoint;
    }
}
```

And my aim is to get single jar file with embedded Tomcat and web service deployed on it. 
Currently my problem is that after `mvn spring-boot:run` i receive exception

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Maya\git\web-services\resources\WebService.wsdl (The system cannot find the file specified)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection.java:90)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(FileURLConnection.java:188)


The full stacktrace is here: http://pastebin.com/Ez3S5CWu
```

Could you help me with the answers for the next questions:

1. Why Spring try to find wsdl via this link `C:\Users\Maya\git\web-services\resources\WebService.wsdl`, but not from the path from `@javax.jws.WebService` annotation? Where should I set up this path?
2. Is it right approach to create single jar with embedded Tomcat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring *is* using the path from the annotation; but as it is a relative path, the current directory (where your app is started rom ) is used to build the full path.

Try

```
wsdlLocation = "classpath:resources/WebService.wsdl"
```

to search through the classpath.

As for question 2, is it the right approach to start with so long as nothing prevents it. Your IT infrastructure might veto it for some reasons.

Comment: `java.io.FileNotFoundException: Unable to load the resource [classpath:resources/IsBankService.wsdl] using the thread context class loader or the current classs class loader`, but i fixed it by adding full path to the wsdl file. Thank you.

Comment: Oops. The problem occurs once again with full path. =(

Comment: could ypu give some more advices for `Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Maya\git\app-services\resources\AppService.wsdl`

Comment: The problem with absolute path is that it may not work when the application is build und runs outside the development environment. So I would really pack the wsdl in the jar (set it under /src/main/resources if you use maven) and access it by the classpath. Make sure it is in the produced jar (unzip it to make sure the build process has set it there.)

Comment: smarquis. i open jar and find wsdl in the root of jar (not in resource folder).

Comment: Trying to use `build-helper-maven-plugin`